# Space Invaders health/array issues

Tags: c#, .net, xna

I've been doing some exercises to learn C#. I've been doing XNA and making a space invaders clone.

So far, everything is dandy, but I have come across some walls when coding.

The issues and the supporting code are as follows:

My top of row of invaders have 2 health points, take 2 hits to destroy and yield more points. However, when one is hit, and destroyed, the rest of the top of row are reduced to 1 HP, and take 1 hit to destroy - which is not my desired result.

The offending code I suspect is:

```
 if (playerBullet != null && Type1Invaders != null)
        {
            Rectangle rectMissile = new Rectangle((int)playerBullet.getX(), playerBullet.getY(), playerBulletIMG.Width, playerBulletIMG.Height);
            for (int count = 0; count < 11; count++)
            {
                Rectangle rectInvader = new Rectangle(Type1Invaders[count].getX(), Type1Invaders[count].getY(), invader1.Width, invader1.Height);
                if (Type1Invaders[count].getVis() && rectMissile.Intersects(rectInvader))
                {
                    Type1Invaders[count].setHP(Type1Invaders[count].getHP() - 1);
                    shootTimer = 0;
                    if (Type1Invaders[count].getHP() == 0)
                    {
                        explosionInstance.Play();
                        playerBullet = null;
                        Type1Invaders[count].setVis(false);
                        score = score + Type1Invaders[count].getPointValue();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

---

My second error resides in how I'm detecting the leftmost and rightmost invaders in a row. When an entire row has been destroyed, I get a nullreferenceerror. (Those are a nightmare..)

Anyway, this is the offending code

The method of finding the left and right most invaders

```
var LeftMost5 = Type5Invaders.Where(i => i.getVis()).FirstOrDefault();
var RightMost5 = Type5Invaders.Where(i => i.getVis()).LastOrDefault();
```

And the if statement is throwing the null error

```
 if (RightMost5.getX() >= RightGameEdge)
        {
            Type5.setDir(-1);
            for (int count = 0; count < 11; count++)
            {
                invaderMoveInstance5.Play();
                Type5Invaders[count].MoveY(8);
            }
        }
```

It only happens with the rightmost, but I can assume it will happen to the left too - I'm assuming I can apply the same logic to fix this error to the left side too.

I can supply more information and snippets if this is not sufficient.

Thanks in advance for the assistance!

Comment: Check your Intersects code - it's possible it's returning "true" for every invader.

Comment: for second issue - where is the case of RightMost5/LeftMost5 are null checked? And what is the default value for your collection?

Comment: for the first issue - what is invader1?

Comment: It's probably not the best solution, but I have 5 classes and 5 arrays, one for each row of invaders. As each row has its own image, XY position, and polymorphs from the parent class from which they get their types and methods from. 

Invader1 through to Invader5.

Answer (score 3):

For the first issue. I suppose that when a bullet kills an invader, you can say that that bullet won't kill another invader. Therefore, you can add a `break;` to stop looping. Like this:

```
if (Type1Invaders[count].getVis() && rectMissile.Intersects(rectInvader))
{
  Type1Invaders[count].setHP(Type1Invaders[count].getHP() - 1);
  shootTimer = 0;
  if (Type1Invaders[count].getHP() == 0)
  {
    explosionInstance.Play();
    playerBullet = null;
    Type1Invaders[count].setVis(false);
    score = score + Type1Invaders[count].getPointValue();
  }
  break;
}
```

---

For the second error, the `FirstOrDefault` method returns `null` in case your collection is empty (after you have killed all type 5 invaders). You simply need to check if it is null or not, like this:

```
var LeftMost5 = Type5Invaders.Where(i => i.getVis()).FirstOrDefault();
var RightMost5 = Type5Invaders.Where(i => i.getVis()).LastOrDefault();

if(RightMost5 != null)
{
    // this means we have a non-null invader
    if (RightMost5.getX() >= RightGameEdge)
    {
        Type5.setDir(-1);
        for (int count = 0; count < 11; count++)
        {
            invaderMoveInstance5.Play();
            Type5Invaders[count].MoveY(8);
        }
    }
}
else
{
    //this means that the invader does not exist anymore, so we do nothing
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the assistance. I'm sure I tried from form of the solution to my second problem, but I don't think I used the else statement. 

However, my issue for problem one still remains regardless of the changes suggested.

Comment: You don't need to use the else statement, it is there just for the sake of completeness. As for issue 1, use the debugger to step trough that for loop line by line and see why it decrements the health of all the invaders on that line.

Comment: Hmm, I've done that. It seems like invaders with 2HP are losing all their HP with one hit. I'll do some more testing.

Comment: I've done some more testing and come up with this. HP is initialised as 2. So when the first invader is hit, it takes away 1, setting that variable to 1. Giving the rest of the invaders the HP of 1. 

Question is now, how do I give an instance of that variable to each invader in the collection..

Comment: That is unlikely if the hp is declared for each invader. Please post the code for your `Invader` class, and/or the code for the `setHP` and `getHP` methods.